# Rails before filter authenticate user - how to authenticate a rest client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mule

I'm writing a Rails app (with Devise) that includes syncing data with another app using Mule.  Mule reads/writes json data via the Rest interface.

In all the controllers that Mule does not access, the app has:

```
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

I would like to add the above statement to all of the controllers.  But, then how would Mule get authenticated?

Could Mule supply a user/password in the URL being submitted?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Basic Auth would get you started.

Comment: Create new controller extends from `ApplicationController` and add this line to it. And use it.